# Why Time always different when calculating time of program

Tags: python-3.x

```
import time
def facto(num):
    if num==1:
       return num
    return num*facto(num-1)
start_time=time.time()
print(facto(5))
print("%s"%(time.time()-start_time)
```

when I run program multiple times some time increased or some time decreased.
it should be same when ever time i run program.

Comment: Why should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your cpu is doing many different things at the same time. One way the cpu can do many things at the same time is by switching between multiple tasks. Tasks in this case are the different programs on your computer (like you web browser, IDE, etc.). The way your computer decides on which tasks to work on at a given time is essentially random. Therefore, depending on how much time your computer decides to work on other things while your program runs, the time it takes for your program will change.

This field is referred to as 'scheduling' (i.e. your cpu schedules which tasks to work on)
https://www.studytonight.com/operating-system/cpu-scheduling

TL;DR: your cpu randomly decides to work on other tasks and does your program later

Answer (score 0):

time.time() returns the time passed since epoch (1 january of 1970) in seconds.
So, time is going to increase.

Now, referring to this expression "time.time()-start_time", is always different because it does not take the same amount of time to the computer to do the calculation in facto(num), even if num is always 5; this is because the processor is always doing some other tasks. What you can do is run the program several times and do a mean and standard deviation, so you can have an estimate of time.